# How to make update without subquery in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have this:

```
with required_sportsman as (
    select sportsman_result_id from sportsman
    where sportsman.sportsman_id = 1
)
update sportsman_result
set shown_result = shown_result + 1
where sportsman_result.sportsman_result_id in (select sportsman_result_id from required_sportsman);
```

But I want to remove the last select: `(select sportsman_result_id from required_sportsman)`

How can I do it?

My tables:

`sportsman_result`:

| column name | data type | constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sports_id | integer |  |
| competition_id_id | integer |  |
| shown_result | integer |  |
| result_date | date |  |
| sportsman_result_id | integer | primary key |

`sportsman`:

| column name | data type | constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first_name | text |  |
| last_name | text |  |
| sports_id | integer |  |
| trainer_id | integer |  |
| sportsman_result_id | integer | foreign key |
| number_of_wins | integer |  |
| year_of_birth | date |  |
| country | text |  |
| sportsman_id | integer | primary key |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PostgreSQL extension `UPDATE ... FROM`:

```
UPDATE sportsman_result AS sr
SET shown_result = sr.shown_result + 1
FROM sportsman AS s
WHERE sr.sportsman_result_id = s.sportsman_result_id
  AND s.sportsman_id = 1;
```

Keeping redundant data like `shown_result` in the database is usually not a good idea.